# Drag and drop circle on same color square?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to make a simple "game" where the user has to drag the red circle on th red square and the blue circle on the blue square. I am new to jQuery and I can't figure how to center the circle perfectly in the square and if the color is wrong to reset the circle to it's original position. Is this achievable?

Here is a fiddle but the drag and drop doesn't work for some unknown reason:

https://jsfiddle.net/1s5qdxzh/

JS code also here:

```
const dragger = document.getElementsByClassName("dragger")[1];

const holders = document.getElementsByClassName('holder');

for(const container of holders) {
    container.addEventListener("dragover", dragover)
    container.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter)
    container.addEventListener("drop", drop)
  }

  function dragover(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  function dragenter(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  function drop() {
    this.append(dragger)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery UI it gives you a lot of shortcuts specialy for this game , i advice you to visit this site : [jqueryui draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)